# reducing the memory consumption by wcf services

Tags: wcf

i have an asp.net and c# application using an wcf service and has been hosted in  IIS

and now the memory consumption by  the wcf service was increasing  with time.

can any one guide me in making the wcf service to consume less space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When memory consumption rises, your service is probably leaking memory. Although a small memory rise is expected to happen during the first 100 or so calls of the web service, it should at one point stabilize around a specific usage with regular usage. You will have to check your service code for anything that could cause this leaking memory. (For example, don't rely too much on the automated garbage collection but assign null to variables that you won't use anymore to free them sooner.)

Answer (score 0):

well for one thing, you can make the WCF service a per call instance. Which means it will create a service instance for each request, and then tear it down afterwards.